# convert java application to a jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, executable-jar

I developed a java application using swings and servlets(IDE used:Netbeans).I want to convert the java application to a jar file.I have gone through some questions in stackoverflow.I am bit confused between converting java program to jar and .exe,Is there any difference between jar and .exe??
Finally I want some guidelines to convert java application to jar in **NETBEABNS**.

I have created a jar file for the program-->It fetches data from database and displays to console..When I run the jar file I am getting class notfoundexception:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver..I think jar could not get the driver path..What is the solution??

Comment: possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649762/how-to-create-exe-file-for-swing-based-project
for making exe

Comment: @Abishek:What is the difference between jar and .exe file.

Comment: Exe file is an executable file ehich can be executed on Microsoft OS.
Jar is very simmilar to Zip files.
The word Jar itself represent a container. Jar file is container of Java Class files. It has not only java class files but also other resources related to the project. Jar file can be executed only if Java is available with you.

Comment: The mysql jdbc driver jar is simply missing in the classpath

Comment: Do I need to set the class path in MANIFEST file..It is like this now:Class-Path: lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin

Comment: provided that directory/file should truly exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like DmitryB said, if you are using `servlets`, you need to generate a war file. To generate war file in **Netbeans**, right click on the project node, select **clean and build**. This will generate a war file in the `<project_directory>/dist/` directory.

Comment: My applcation uses database,so what if I want to import this jar file in another computer??Do we need to change the code and get new class files???

Comment: what kinda db ? embedded db or the other one like MySQL  ?

Comment: you don't have to change the code. I hope you are using properties file to store/fetch the mysql url, username and password. Apart from this there is nothing else you gotta change

Comment: I have used a seperate class(which includes database name,driver,username and psw) to connect to database,you mean these parameters has to be changed in another computer?? Also what about the tables??Does they need to be created in another computer??

Comment: Yes, unless the url, username and password are same, and the same db is installed in the other system, you don't have to make any changes. As a side note, hard coding the database login credentials is a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you...So what if I don't want to hard code..Is there any solution??

Comment: you can store them in a properties file. Check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) example

Answer (score 2):

If you have servlets, you need to build a war file to deploy to tomcat. Netbeeans will help you do that, just make sure you tell it its a web app.

Comment: My applcation uses database,so what if I want to import this jar file in another computer??Do we need to change the code and get new class files???